# Getting error after changing in info.plist react native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am implementing the code push in my ios react native.
I followed the tutorials and made some changes. I did changes on info.plist file. and I am getting  below error

> error: unable to read property list from file: /Users/abhigyangaurav/Documents/Untitled/dclm-mobile-app/dclmapp/ios/DCLM/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.) (in target 'DCLM' from project 'DCLM')

what i did wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <!-- ...other configs... -->
    
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
          <dict>
            <key>codepush.appcenter.ms</key>
            <dict><!-- read the ATS Apple Docs for available options --></dict>
          </dict>
        </dict>
    
        <!-- ...other configs... -->
      </dict>
    <dict>
        <!-- ...other configs... -->
    
        <key>CodePushPublicKey</key>
            <string>
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwJBGud67ZxzxYRp+J6WY
    QGdHwhFy2pwHn6f8bopqw3QZOt40ZYbgoWbSorsQu3xIssoPP+oQeX/SyUMjRDbs
    JyxjV/TGXQhUKL6Ez27W+bIOA5tmNA7YjRnYeRmNIedcjmzHxyBU3Wg11B6d/kdo
    UXIOz0CQxbFm1s6iW/UBnOyv/dwbfpzTJKfbLE8oflcDIoZ1pDamuaYilbYB1SJy
    
    +QIDAQAB</string>
    
        <!-- ...other configs... -->
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <!-- ...other configs... -->
    
        <key>CodePushDeploymentKey</key>
            <string>JtcoHPzOB35f4mgAkHcl6ix</string>
    
        <!-- ...other configs... -->
      </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>en</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>DCLM</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>localhost</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>We need your permission to use your camera phone</string>
        <key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This allows you to securely sign in into your app</string>
        <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>UIAppFonts</key>
        <array>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-RegularItalic.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-Regular.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-MediumItalic.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-Medium.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-LightItalic.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-Light.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-ExtraLightItalic.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-ExtraLight.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-ExtraBoldItalic.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-ExtraBold.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-BoldItalic.otf</string>
            <string>MTNBrighterSans-Bold.otf</string>
            <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
            <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
            <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>Feather.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
            <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
            <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
            <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
            <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
            <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
            <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
            <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
            <string>Roboto_medium.ttf</string>
            <string>Roboto.ttf</string>
            <string>rubicon-icon-font.ttf</string>
        </array>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
        <array>
            <string>armv7</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: Open the project in Xcode- it will show you which line is causing the issue